# Using Windows/IE proxy settings in a .NET Windows application

Tags: .net, security, proxy

How does one get a Windows .NET application to use the proxy settings configured in Internet Settings?

Answer (score 2):

While it was posted elsewhere that the HttpWebRequest uses the Windows/IE proxy settings by default, what was not posted was that if the proxy required authentication, the authentication is NOT used by default.  That can be corrected by adding the following to the app.config:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>
```

One little bit of configuration that fixed the problem, at least for me.